# Saving position locations flooding the database

Tags: android, database-design, gps, gis

I developed an andoroid app for saving runners tracks-routs.
Because it is a running app i need to report location every 10 seconds.
That means that each 10sec the lang lat being saved as local copy on the sqlite on the device
and on the webserver using webservice call.

The aim of the app is to show the exact position in each certain time
and the speed of the person.

My friends and I installed the app 3 weeks and used it almost every day for few hours
and my db is flooded about 6,000,000 records - record for each 
I will not be able to keep running it because the server will space will be be over.

Is there any other way i could save the posuitions or any other architecture or algorithm that will
allow me to know the exact position of person in any point of the track and his speed?

Comment: "Because it is a running app i need to report location every 10 seconds." Start by questioning that assumption.

Comment: I think you'll get about 6 million rows if 30 people report their position every 10 seconds, 24 hours a day, for three weeks.  So maybe the part that turns position reporting *off* isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't you only have:
3 (weeks) * 7 (days) * 3 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 6 (10 sec intervals) = 22680 records per runner?

one approach could be to store run data as a string and store one record in db per "run" (or one per hour, or n minutes)

string could be formated to only store starting location and offsets like: "36.234234234,-114.3434434,0.004,0.006,0.002,0.000 ...

Comment: about 30 friends, and i guess some of them forgot to turn it off...so it kept logging. I plan that more than 1000 people will use it.Is saving per hours is possiable = 360 records its a long string...almost 5000digits...and is that the best way? i read now about idea of saving it in files is that better solution?

Comment: you can also store only "corners", so if runner runs from A to B in 10 sec then from B to C in 10 and his direction and pace are within a set threshold, you can log a run from A to C in 20 sec

Comment: Great Idea! i thought about it, but how i will know whether there was a straigh line or some corner - how i know the DIRECTION? how i can know where is the corners and know where to log? there is some kind of algorithm for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line - you can use something like this to see how far point is from line..to detect corner, play around with some arbitrary distances, like 5 or 10 percent and see how it goes

Comment: at different timestamp same location is possible say at 10:30 u are at x and moved to y then came to x position... at 10:32 you are at x again... this means the locations received are like that. if i will not save the same location with diffrent timestamp, how will i know when exactly i moved to other location?

Comment: there will be a tradeoff between accuracy and the amount of data you log.  start with something simple and if your app takes off make it better and better

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to reduce space requirements of track logs. Basically you can cluster and filter nearby locations to a point and alsomif logger stays on the same point for two or more consequent reads, you can increment a counter on the position record instead of creating a new one.

Timestamp the beginning of the track and skip the rest, you can calculate time info since reading is done in fixed intervals.

You can look at the following pdf for additional information.

[http://www.activelivingresearch.org/files/DataReduction_GPS_Workshop.pdf]